# Hibernate JPA mapping for column referencing a composite key column, but no foreign key association

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

The given schema is not real; it is an example.  This effort is useful for ORM mapping POJOs to legacy database schemas that cannot change.

Two tables, Person and Car:

- Person has a composite key of firstName and lastName
- Car references Person.lastName in a OneToOne, nullable column of its own
- Person and Car are not related in the database schema; no foreign key

**Database Tables**

> ```
>  -------------------------   -------------------------
> | Person                  | | Car                     |
> |-------------------------| |-------------------------
> | <PK> first_name: String | | owner_last_name: String |
> | <PK> last_name: String  |  -------------------------
>  -------------------------
> ```

**Java Classes**

```
class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name="first_name")
    String firstName;

    @Id
    @Column(name="last_name")
    String lastName;
}

class Car {
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_last_name", referencedColumnName="last_name")
    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    Person owner;
}
```

With the given example JPA annotations, the Hibernate error is:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(last_name) of com.example.Car.owner referencing com.example.Person not mapped to a single property
```

I would like to have the correct Person object when retrieving the Car object.  Again, the schema cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Embeddeble` and `@EmbeddedId` to create a composite key and map it with your Entity. For example:

```
@Embeddable
public class PersonCompositeID {

    @Column(name="first_name")
    String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    String lastName;

    //getter, setter methods
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Person")
 public class Person {

     @EmbeddedId
     private PersonCompositeID  personCompositeID;

  /*setter getter methods */
 }
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Ashish, I originally used this pattern, but decided to remove that extra layer since my @Id example worked the same and was clearer to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for mapping a composite identifier which are listed in the hibernate documentation here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id

The hibernate documentation includes a warning against using the IdClass annotation.

> Warning This approach is inherited from the EJB 2 days and we
>   recommend against its use. But, after all it's your application and
>   Hibernate supports it.

```
@Embeddable
class PersonId {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(PersonId.class)    
class Person {
    @Id
    String firstName;

    @Id
    String lastName;
}
```

That being said, there are a few problems with your model. How can Car's owner relationship be one-to-one if in fact the last name in Person is not unique? It seems to me that Car's owner relationship must be one-to-many. Stated differently, if Person's last name is truly unique, then it should be used as the sole primary key thus simplifying the model.

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_last_name", referencedColumnName="last_name")
    @OneToMany
    Set<Person> owners;
}
```

Perhaps it would be simpler to just create the entities without the relationships, and use a (criteria or hql) query to find the related objects.

Find all Persons who could possibly be owners of this car:

```
"select Person person, Car car where person.lastName = car.lastName and car.id=?"
```

Comment: I tried to make it very clear that the model is not going to change.  It seems that Hibernate does not support associating these unrelated entities.  So, using queries may be the only way to force an association.